# About ubuntu as server and configuring ip tables

Tags: installation, networking, iptables

Please help me to setup a linux based server machine for sharing internet connection in my network.
Since I am a new user, please assist me ...

Comment: These two links should get you started. [Internet/ConnectionSharingDHCP3](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharingDHCP3), and [Internet/ConnectionSharing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing).

Answer (score 0):

funny you ask - I was perusing the Ubuntu Server Guide for 13.04 just now. You might find it helpful:

https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/index.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.